# How to be able to interact with a view after hiding a container view?

Tags: swift

I have a container view within my viewContolerA and it is hidden by default. On a click of buttonA the container property isHidden is set to false so the user can now interact with the container. A buttonB in the container is to hide the container. Once clicked the container is hidden but I cant interact with the the buttonA or any other sub-view again ? What am I doing wrong? ( Swift3 )

**clarification:**

The container is a subview of my viewContolerA and so do buttonA

Comment: maybe checking you view hierarchy to see if your views overlap as top view will consume touches. Also good to double check the `userInteraction` property. If `userInteraction` is disabled touches will be ignored.

Comment: Somehow you succeeded button action in hidden content. Apple may reject your app.

Comment: all looks good and I guess with hiding the container the app still serve the hidden container and there is something missing to return the app response to the super view

Answer (score 0):

You can not interact with subviews once you hide the container view so you should not put hide and unhide buttons inside the container.

Comment: This is not what I'm saying, I'm trying to interact with sub-views and buttons in the super view where the container was not hidden and was a sub-view of the whole view